# Como carregar videos dentro de uma div com <select>

Tags: html, jquery

Olá !

Eu tenho uma select com os values e os títulos dos videos. Quero selecionar o video pelo value e carregar dentro de uma div.

SELECIONE O VÍDEO...
               Vídeo-1
               Vídeo-2
               Vídeo-3

Como que ficaria uma jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente você pode fazer desta forma, inserindo uma tag `video` (HTML5) em uma `div` de acordo com a opção selecionada. O `value` das `option`s você pode colocar a URL (origem) do respectivo vídeo.

> Importante consultar **[nesta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)** as compatibilidades,
>   opções e outros atributos da tag `video`.

**Código:**

```js
$("#videos").change(function(){
   var src = $(this).val();
   var source = '<video width="400" controls><source src="'+src+'" type="video/mp4"></video>';
   $("#player").html(source);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="videos">
   <option value="">Selecione um vídeo...</option>
   <option value="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">Vídeo-1</option>
   <option value="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4">Vídeo-2</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="player"></div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. No meu caso carreguei os vídeos localmente. Depois é só mandar buscar no servidor. Muitíssimo obrigado.

Comment: @xavier, considere marcar a resposta como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079